# fuzzy search using cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have node for user with FirstName, LastName properties. Now I want to search some value in both properties from both site. Let I have to explain.

```
FirstName  LastName
---------  --------
Manish     Pal
Pal        Dharmesh
Rajpal     Yadav
sharma     shreepal
```

Now I want to search which node's firstname or lastname contain *'pal'*. 
I have written query like this.

```
START users=node(*) 
WHERE (users.FirstName =~ '(?i)pal.*' OR users.LastName =~ '(?i)pal.*') 
RETURN users;
```

It gives me just 2 nodes, but I want all node with is containing *'pal'*

If I try like this

```
START users=node(*) 
WHERE (users.FirstName =~ '(?i)*.pal.*' OR users.LastName =~ '(?i)*.pal.*') 
RETURN users;
```

It is giving me following error.

*"PatternSyntaxException"*

*Dangling meta character '*' near index 4 (?i)*.ant.* ^*

I have set example [here](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=64lxja) for your ready reference.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second query contains invalid regular expression syntax. I think you mean:

```
START users=node(*) 
WHERE (users.FirstName =~ '(?i).*pal.*' OR users.LastName =~ '(?i).*pal.*') 
RETURN users
```

Note the difference to the query in your post:

- `'(?i)*.pal.*'` in your post, and
- `'(?i).*pal.*'` in the above query

The asterisk `*` means **the expression before me [the asterisk] may appear an arbitrary number of times, including zero**. But `(?i)` is no regular expression but just a modifier to ignore the case of the actual expression. I think you meant `.*`. The regular expression `.` matches any character, the asterisk allows any character to appear an arbitrary number of times.

Thus, `'(?i).*pal.*'` says: **[ignore case] <arbitrary number of any characters><the exact character sequence: "pal"><arbitrary number of any characters>**

The above query returned four results for me:

```
users.FirstName  | users.LastName
---------------------------------
sharma           | shreepal
Rajpal           | Yadav
Pal              | Dharmesh     
Manish           | Pal
```

Which is what you wanted, if I understood your correctly.

Comment: My pleasure :-) If the answer was correct, you might want to accept it, so that all can see this problem is solved.

Comment: ya, that's true. but I am not a regular user of stackoverflow, so I am able to do change status of this question as accepted. could you please guide me? so, next time I will be do. thanks

Comment: Of course: To the left of an answer-text, there are two elements you should see: 1st, the current voting state of the answer (this answer currently 1) und the arrows to vote the answer up or down. Below this voting state, you - as the question raiser - should see a hollow check mark. If - and only if - you find an answer satisfactory, you can click on this check mark which should turn it solid green. Then, you accepted the respective answer. Note that you can only accept one answer in case multiple answers are given.

Comment: I have done it. did you seen my another post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18051685/neo4j-2-0-startnoder-and-union-all