# neo4j 2.0 - startnode(r) and union all

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have created relationship named 'friend' between 2 node and want to know, which node is request sender? I seen some post on stackoverflow regarding startnode(r), but I cannot understand how to use? can some one explain me with use case?

One more thing, I want to join 2 result sets with ***"union/union all"*** clause. How can I do this?

thanks.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit? I.e. what do you understand under "request sender"? Could you perhaps give an example query and what you would expect the result of the query to be? I assume you are using Cypher, correct?

Comment: Please have a look http://console.neo4j.org/?id=dxwc8z. Please check relationship carefully. e.g. In first relationship node1 connected with node2. means node1 has sent request to node2 and node2 accepted it (see ApprovalStatus=1 property). Now, As per this relationship I want node1 as a Request sender. Second (for union), check another post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947903/search-list-with-mutual-count-2nd-try/17974354?noredirect=1#comment26317336_17974354. I have to create 2 result set. 1st for connected node's list, another not-connected node's list and want to show with union

Comment: Your console is broken, can you fix that.

Comment: hi @MichaelHunger, my console has data here. : http://console.neo4j.org/?id=dxwc8z